# Creating a resizeDidHappen event

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am interested in responding to a window resize event in an Ember component and thought I could do the following:

```
resizeListener: function() {
    var self = this;
    jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(self, self.trigger('resizeDidHappen')));
}.on('didInsertElement'),
```

I had originally had the preferred `this.$(window)` instead of the global `jQuery(window)` but I was afraid that potentially the localised selector might be a part of the problem. Anyway, in both cases I get the following error whenever I resize the window:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
    undefined is not a function   vendor.js:13693 
    Backburner.run  vendor.js:13716 
    Backburner.join     vendor.js:34296 
    run.join    vendor.js:34349 
    run.bind    vendor.js:4759 
    jQuery.event.dispatch   vendor.js:4427 
    jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to specify an event namespace and to unbind it on component destruction.
The event namespace can be uniquely driven from `this.get('elementId')`.

```js
App.ResizeAwareComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  resizeEventName: function() {
    return 'resize.' + this.get('elementId');
  }.property('elementId')
  bindResizeEvent: function() {
    jQuery(window).on(this.get('resizeEventName'), Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
  unbindResizeEvent: function() {
    jQuery(window).off(this.get('resizeEventName'));
  }.on('willDestroyElement'),
  handleResize: function() {
    console.log("It works!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Very nice. Works perfectly.

Comment: I think the choice of whether to extend the Component class, use a Mixin, or just do as a "one off" is a design decision but this answer's scoping the listener to just the component plus the cleanup afterward is really good. I have marked this as the correct answer for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not giving a function to `Ember.run.bind`. Your code is calling `self.trigger('resizeDidHappen')` immediately, then giving the return value (which is likely `undefined`) to `Ember.run.bind`. You need to give it a function, not the result of calling a function.

Also, you don't really need the `bind` call *and* the `self` variable, just one or the other. There's a few ways to rewrite your particular code to work, so I'll give you the readable version and the short version.

Readable version:

```
resizeListener: function() {
    var self = this;
    jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
        self.trigger('resizeDidHappen');
    });
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

Short version:

```
resizeListener: function() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.trigger, ['resizeDidHappen']));
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

Comment: I did actually start out with a function reference (aka, your "readable version") ... in any event, I will try both your suggestions. I particularly like the short version :)

Comment: Ok it does appear to work when I do nothing more than this in a virgin controller. In the component where I was experiencing the problem I still get the undefined problem but this needs to be considered a separate problem. Thanks for you help ... love the compact form.

Comment: btw, do you know if a listener setup with this approach becomes not visible (aka, hidden not gone from DOM) ... how does this effect the callback? Also, is this different if the callback is setup when in this "invisible" state?

Comment: What do you mean by invisible or hidden?

Comment: A parent DOM element has a `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` are the most likely culprits. For me the perpetrator is a Bootstrap tab-pane.

Comment: You're listening to the resize event on the window, not any particular DOM element. The function should always fire regardless of the state of your DOM.

Comment: That is what I'd assume. Ok, I need to dig into it some more. I wish the ST was a little more transparent but you can't have everything.

Comment: Due to the completeness of a new response I changed the correct answer but yours is still entirely correct. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
App.ResizeAwareComponent = Ember.Component.extend({ 
  resizeListener: function() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  handleResize: function(){
    console.log("It works!");
  }
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xodoyagole/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

I dug this up from the documentation (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_bind)

Comment: I will try this again but this is where I started out. :)

Comment: I did try it again ... along with GJK's compact suggestion ... and yup it works. I was getting confused by some other code that is throwing the above mentioned stack trace (which find nearly impossible to debug). Anyway, when isolating the problem there is no denying it works. Thanks for your help.